# Conversion failing when applying PIVOTED SCRIPT

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, ssms

i am having a data conversion issues when applying this un-pivoted script on my dynamic columns SSRS report .every time SSRS Report is executed the header columns are supposedly to change .

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Temp') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE ##Temp; 

        DECLARE @ObjectName VARCHAR(100) = '[AdventureWorks2016].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]' ,
            @KeyColumn VARCHAR(100)       = '[SalesOrderID]';

        DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX)= '' ,
            @Values NVARCHAR(MAX)= '' ,
            @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)= '';

        SELECT  @ColumnNames += ',

    ' + QUOTENAME([ShipDate]) ,
                @Values += ',

    ' + QUOTENAME([ShipDate]) + ' = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), '
                + QUOTENAME([ShipDate]) + ')'
        FROM    [AdventureWorks2016].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
        WHERE   '[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]' = @ObjectName
                AND [ShipDate] <> @KeyColumn;


SET @SQL = N'Select * into ##Temp
FROM
(
  SELECT ' + @KeyColumn + @Values + '
  FROM ' + @ObjectName + '
) AS DRV
UNPIVOT
(
  Value FOR ColumnName IN (' + STUFF(@ColumnNames, 1, 1, '') + ')
) AS UnPVT;';
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
        SELECT  *
        FROM    ##Temp
```

Comment: Would be good if you add the error message. Just a thought: Can it be that the unpivot is converting the column header to text type?

Comment: You nor anyone else can debug code that cannot be seen. Before you execute that query, you need to capture it somehow (using print or select - depending on the size) so you can examine the query your code generates to understand the error.

Comment: @Aldert, @SMor  this the error up on executing``` Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.``` the shipdate column is where its failing to convert not sure which steps i need to take .

Comment: In you where clause you compare a date to a nvarchar. This is why you get an error. Convert the nvarchar to date first. I expect you can use ToDate(@KeyColumn).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand much of this... You are comparing ShipDate which is a DateTime column against SaleSorderID which an INT and has not date info contained in it? You then compare a literal '[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]' to a variable that contains another literal '[SalesOrderID]' . I think you need to show what your real data looks like (rather than the AW sample) and what you are trying to achieve. If this was your real data there would be no need to unpivot it as it is normalised anyway.